# (htaccess) How to make a file only accessable by host Server and prevent direct access?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I'm using Apache and lets say there is a file at "images/sample.jpg".

- With **.htaccess**, how can i make it **appearing** on the website and **then prevent** the direct access by url (*for example, direct url like "http://www.abc.com/images/sample.jpg"*) ?
- If possible, i also want the solution to affect on all sub-folders below the ".htaccess" file.

*Additional Note:

After one day of getting below answers, i found all solutions logically work, but problem with Firefox. I mean, the below answers are giving the solution while testing on every browser but not with Firefox.*

Comment: Did you try using @pyrate anwer?

Comment: @anubhava Please see my comment below him.

Comment: Your RewriteCond should be: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a LOT more going on to prevent hotlinking of images, than an .htaccess rule. However, the basis of what you'd want in your htaccess to prevent image hotlinking is :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

[Apache ReWrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: Please jump to my next thread with more clear explaination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access

Comment: All solutions (including this one) normally work, but problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

This is called "hotlinking" - I suggest reading up on it first, as there is more to it than just a line or to of code in your .htaccess. This page is decent: http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://i.imgur.com/qX4w7.gif [L]
```

This will show an image from imgur, however I sometimes like to go further and host alternative images from my own host - if it's a competitor, for instance, you can have a lot of fun ;)

Comment: Please, I'm not so clear about "imgur". What is it about? Do i need to use that line?

Comment: This is why I posted the link to the site (though many others can be found through Google). This is just an example - imgur is just an image hosting web site. You can put any URL there, even your own image - but you'd need to have a different rule to stop "recursion".

Comment: I'm testing on my "localhost/example" web folder and it is not working like what i want. I mean, all images on my site are showing 'imgur warning image'.

Comment: As I said, the code was an example... but did you change mysite.com to your own URL?

Comment: I'm using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?localhost\test/ [NC]`. Then on my site, all images are showing just 'imgur image'. Not their proper image. I just want to PREVENT ONLY WHEN the image is called by direct url. But ALLOWED to be appearing on the website.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want, but there's a mistake in your code. Get rid of `\test` and try that - but please... go read that URL I posted and you will be able to figure this stuff out yourself :)

Comment: Same result however i change the server path. And actually, the line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]` is not needed as i test. This only line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$` is enough. But whatever, the result is same as i mentioned above.

Comment: Please jump to my next thread with more clear explaination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access

Comment: The problem is in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$`. WITHOUT IT, it works well.

Comment: So, you fix hotlinking by hotlinking ? #nice

Answer (score 1):

Use this chunk of code to prevent hotlinking:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

This could help you out: http://www.selfseo.com/story-18469.php

Comment: @4lvin Try this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/.*$ [NC] ` You use backslash after localhost.

Comment: @4lvin I changed something in code above, tested on my localhost: now it works. I missed the 2nd line.

Comment: Please jump to my next thread with more clear explaination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access

Comment: All solutions (including this one) normally work, but problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure but this should guide you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule (images/sample.jpg)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Please jump to my next thread with more clear explaination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access

Comment: All solutions (including this one) normally work, but problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments looks like this is what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,NC]
```

I have tested it on my localhost and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Please jump to my next thread with more clear explaination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access

Comment: All solutions (including this one) normally work, but problem with Firefox.