# How to prevent a file from direct URL Access?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I'm using Apache and I have a sample web folder on my **Local Host**, like:

```
      http://localhost/test/
```

---

Files in the `test` folder:

```
     index.html  
     sample.jpg  
     .htaccess
```

---

Sample source of `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="sample.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the website at `http://localhost/test/`, it will simply show the image `sample.jpg' on the page.

---

**Problem:**

- I want to prevent the image showing as `http://localhost/test/sample.jpg` directly in the url bar.

**Note:** *I found that the solutions below work when tested on every browser **except Firefox**.*

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Returns 403, if you access images directly, but allows them to be displayed on site.

**Note:** It is possible that when you open some page with image and then copy that image's path into the address bar you can see that image, it is only because of the browser's cache, in fact that image has not been loaded from the server *(from Davo, full comment below)*.

Answer (score 25):

rosipov's rule works great!

I use it on live sites to display a blank or special message ;) in place of a direct access attempt to files I'd rather to protect a bit from direct view. I think it's more fun than a 403 Forbidden.

So taking rosipov's rule to redirect any *direct* request to {gif,jpg,js,txt} files to 'messageforcurious' :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.ltd [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.ltd.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|txt)$ /messageforcurious [L]
```

I see it as a polite way to disallow direct acces to, say, a CMS *sensible files* like xml, javascript... with security in mind: To all these bots scrawling the web nowadays, I wonder what their algo will make from my 'messageforcurious'.

Answer (score 11):

Based on your comments looks like this is what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,NC]
```

I have tested it on my localhost and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me only that my language handling now impedes access to the resource since it adds (de/|fr/|en/), no idea how to add that in the 'match-syntax' ...

Answer (score 9):

First of all, find where the main apache’s config file httpd.conf is located. If you use Debian, it should be here: `/etc/apache/httpd.conf`. Using some file editor like Vim or Nano open this file and find the line that looks as follows:

```
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

then remove word Indexes and save the file. The line should look like this one:

```
Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

After it is done, restart apache (e.g. /etc/init.d/apache restart in Debian). That’s it!

Answer (score 2):

For me this was the **only** thing that worked and it worked great:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*  
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tif|pdf|wav|wmv|wma|avi|mov|mp4|m4v|mp3|zip?)$ - [F]
```

Found it at:
https://simplefilelist.com/how-can-i-prevent-direct-url-access-to-my-files-from-outside-my-website/

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|mp4)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

Answer (score -1):

When I used it on my Webserver, can I only rename local host, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```