# .htaccess block all in directory exept index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I wrote this script to deny all exept index.php

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from All

<Files *>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

However links like http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg are still shown. How is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "links are still shown?" `.htaccess` won't change links. What it will change is how the server responds to a request to a specific file/directory. What do you see when you visit a page that's not index.php?

Comment: other pages gives error, but when you request /image.jpg it is not error. I want to deny all, including images.

Comment: Do you want to provide access to files via index.php (such as image files)? If not, change the top `Order allow,deny` to `Order deny,allow`.

Comment: Than I can't go to index.php and the image is still visible. I want to deny everything exept index.php, which is not loading any images from the folder.

Comment: That's what I thought. The following link will provide the solution you need. I tested it and it worked. Keep in mind you might need to do a hard refresh to clear your browser's cache. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10236791/1085891

Comment: Did that last suggestion work?