# disable browsable folder with images in Joomla (with Igniter gallery)

Tags: joomla2.5, google-image-search, browsable

I am using Joomla 2.5.

My webpage has some static pages with images that I can edit via Joomla administrator. Igniter gallery is used to administrate images.

Today I found that some images appear in google image search, but when user clicks on image it shows the list of images (it allows to browse the directory): for example, one images from google goes to http://ziedireizija.lv/images/igallery/original/1-100/

Is it somehow possible to change this? Is it possible to make this gallery not browsable and redirect user to the page?

I believe this happens, because images in this folder are not seen directly on webpage, but only via "lightbox". The page shows only image thumbnails, then user clicks on thumbnail and page displays big image. I think that when this big image appears in google search the the url of image leads user to browsable folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to put an index.html file in the folder. You can add a redirect if you like or just leave the file blank.

If you have the access, you can also edit the httpd.conf file to block folder browsing if you like. Info on how to do that here - http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the .htaccess file. Hope this can help you:

[(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access)