# after using .htaccess for redirect jpg to html i am not able to see images on my own page

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I put the following code on my .htaccess and both that images are now not showing on any of my webpages, what i have to do to show on my pages but not accessible directly through image url ?

```
redirect /upload/2014/1/img.jpg http://www.moviesreview.cu.cc/upload/2014/1/img.html
redirect /upload/2014/1/454545.jpg http://www.moviesreview.cu.cc/upload/2014/1/454545.html
```

Comment: You can see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access

Comment: Open your developer console and look in the network tab to see what happens when it tries to load the images.