# Using .htaccess, prevent users from accessing images in directories

Tags: html, .htaccess

I Tried Using this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Which works for the Folder but if you write the specific image name like this

```
www.example.com/images/pictures.jpg
```

You're Still able to view the image, Is there anyway disable that to?

I also tried using this which does the same thing

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com[NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Comment: Original answer is here ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access