# Redirect the page to back if URL changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

My Homepage URL is **//localhost:8090** it will run **index.html** with **main.js**

If the URL is changed to **//localhost:8090/icons/sample.png**. I have to redirect the user to previous page as **//localhost:8090**.

I tried:

**main.js**

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("icons") > -1) 
 {
     window.history.back();
 }
```

It doesn't work. The page simply display the image.

Comment: Images can't run Javascript. Where is this script running?

Comment: the request is hitting an image resource so no js,put one htaccess file   Deny from all

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Do you want to block access to icons directory?

Comment: Have you tried `onunload` from the pages that are trying to navigate to the image?

Comment: @Emma Yes I want to block icons directory

Comment: You will have to use mod_rewrite / .htaccess to redirect the request to the image file to a php file, which will then send a http status code 302 which redirects the browser back to the index

Comment: @MerlinDenker am not using php

Comment: Okay. Then If you can put something like index.php or index.html file of size zero. This may sort your problem. I have tried in PHP projects, which works.

Comment: then you can redirect to a html file that contains a javascript or meta redirect

Comment: what webserver are you using ?

Comment: @johnSmith am using node

Answer (score 4):

In modern browsers(IE8+, FF3.6+, Chrome), you can just listen to the hashchange event on window.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
  window.history.back();
 /* things */
});
```

In some old browsers, you need a timer that continually checks location.hash. If you're using jQuery, there is a plugin that does exactly that.

```
function hashHandler(){
this.oldHash = window.location.hash;
this.Check;

var that = this;
var detect = function(){
    if(that.oldHash!=window.location.hash){
       window.history.back();
    }
};
this.Check = setInterval(function(){ detect() }, 100);
}

var hashDetection = new hashHandler();
```

Do you work on hash change event.

Comment: I need to redirect only if the url having 'icons'. Because the above code restricts all the API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Returns 403 if you access image directly, but allows them to be displayed on site.

NOTE: it is possible that when you open some page with image and than copy that image's path into the address bar you can see that image, it is only because of the browser's cache, in fact that image has not been loaded from the server.

[Credits to Ruslan Osipov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236791/3872635)