# Prevent direct PDF file access from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, pdf

Redirected from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access/10236791#10236791), I need to prevent access of `PDF` (or any other) file types, when someone access it using direct URL.

**The Problem**

Say you had a PDF file that you’d like visitors on your own site to download.

However, if someone were to copy this link and call it from a browser window directly, or if they were to post the link to you PDF on another website then the document shall not be accessible. By default it is.

I am successful in hiding the pdf file path in address bar and the url formed is `http://localhost/myproject/web/viewer.php?id=11&name=sample.pdf`, but in console one can see the complete path like `http://localhost/myproject/document/11/sample.pdf`.

This code redirects successfully on second time page reload, but not when I select `Open in new tab` from console.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(pdf) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(pdf)$ http://google.com/ [NC]
```

Used below code in `.htaccess` to prevent access

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ - [F]
```

Somehow it does not work accurately. It shows file forbidden message only if I  hit `CTRL+SHIFT+R` key otherwise using the file URL I  can still access it.

I want to prevent the pdf file showing as `http://localhost/myproject/document/11/sample.pdf` directly in the url bar

Comment: Have you tried removing conditions on HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: @manurat which conditions you're talking about ?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}..

Comment: Could you post the code once.

Comment: I mean `RewriteEngine on RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ - [F] ` without the two condition lines.
It works for me on a sample localhost.

Comment: @manurat it blocks the viewing of that pdf too.

Comment: yes, but that 's your goal, is it not?
In order to let your visitors download the file you can write a script that handles a specific request (somewhat similar to answer below ) and forces download through appropiate headers.

Comment: That's not the ultimate goal. User is able to view that file but can not access directly using URL. I have prevented it too but guess it must be using browser cache to load the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a database, maybe you could store the file/s in a blob field. This way you can easily write code to protect the file how you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can store PDF files not in `webroot` folder and return it content use PHP. For example for user URL will be like:

http://localhost/myproject/document.php?hash=some_hash`

and on file `document.php` you will get document hash from `$_GET` parametr  use `file_get_contents` function. Also in this case you can allow access only once

I hope it will help