# Best way to secure directory but still make php files executable by public

Tags: php

I'm trying to better secure my PHP application.

Goal: Cut off directory listing access for php files, but still execute them via browser by a user.

I currently have the var/www/html/ directory and it's sub-directories owned by www-data, I am a member of the www-data group as is www-data, the owner has read/write/execute access. My program files are inside sub-directories and set to 644 - so you can't see their contents, but the directory still lists out the contents in a browser. When I cut off the public ability to see the directory listing, I can't execute them anymore.... I know I'm on the right trail here, but I'm obviously screwing something up. I did play around with '.' prefixes to hide files, but that seems a bit low tech and non-reliable. Do I need to shuffle the groups/users around? I was just exploring a live site installed with a CMS and it seems it has this kind of ability and a similar setup... but it works.

I came across this answer, but is this really a secure option?

[(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access)

Comment: As which user runs apache/php?

Comment: If I edited the following from my apache .conf file, but made it more specific to my program directory....

`<Directory /var/www/ADD IN MY PROGRAM PATH>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>`

?