# htaccess codes did not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is EXACTLY the same case as: [(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access)

But, no one of codes provided by answers work for me. I tried 1 by 1, then tried to combine, but still not works. Here is my code:

```
# prevent direct image url access
# ----------
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)://(www\.)?example\.com.*$ [NC]

    # this not works
    RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ - [F]

    # and this
    RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ - [F,NC]

    # and this
    RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ https://example.com/wp-login.php [NC,R,L]

    # even by combining them
# ----------
# /prevent direct image url access
```

The case simulation:
`index.php` has `<img src="test.png" alt="">` and should be normally accessible. The requirement is: `http://example.com/test.png` shouldn't be accessible.

I use WordPress in wp-engine, and i think WordPres's default rewrite doesn't cause the problem since the code from answers are placed above WordPress rewrite.

**UPDATE**

I use PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 on Apache 2 on wp engine

Comment: How did you test them? Did you embed the images in a nonallowed site? Or did you just try to access them directly with your browser?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, i updated the question. I test by accessing the current site

Comment: take note that after editing htaccess file, you should clear your cache before testing if new rule works or not.

Comment: well, they didnt work both on local or wpengine. -_- no idea why

Answer (score 0):

Your rules basically work for me, except for one thing:

The `(s)` is not doing what you think it does.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
```

With parentheses you define a group, which doesn't make any sense at this point. If you remove the `(s)`, it works for http.

If you want to use https too you have to write it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
```

The `?` will make the preceding character (or group, if in parentheses) optional.

Comment: urgh, i updated again the question. So, i just remove the (s) as your advice. But still doesnt do both on localhost & wp-engine.