# Protect images from direct URL access?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

I'm currently working on a project using php, apache server and symfony. What Im trying to achieve is to prevent my images accessed via http://localhost:8000/img/logoSmall.png directly in the URL bar. I already tried Iusing the `Option All -Indexes` but it does not work, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, also I tried some things from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access) post like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ - [F]
```

and changing

`Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews`

to

```
Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

I'm also sure that my httpd.conf file has  `AllowOverride All`

I really don't know what else to do. I've been stuck in this for too long, If you see any errors in my solutions, or you have any suggestions I would veyr much appreciete them. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I do want to continue displaying the images in my site, what I don't want is allow other users access them with the direct URL.

Comment: Do you want to prevent access to the files no matter what, or just when they are directly accessed from the URL bar? Sorry, I assumed the former in my answer.

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this. It's not worth bothering with

Comment: Well, you can fully prevent access with my answer. I was assuming OP was going to load the files with PHP or something into data URIs, so that the would-be URLs for the images are never used.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but in my case I used some folder (Uploads) for files uploaded by users (profile pictures etc), and then I needed to show those files only for certain users (account owner and his contacts).

My solution: 
1) in security.yml close uploads folder from all users except super admin

```
security:
   access_control:
       - { path: ^/uploads/, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

2) If you need users to be a able to download files from server create  controller to handle this

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

class DownloadController extends Controller
{
    public function downloadAction(Request $request, $filepath = null)
    {
        if ($filepath){
            $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filepath);

            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same but still, my URL is public and unauthorized user can see the image

Comment: Check your security.yaml and make sure your controller is behind the firewall with enabled security.  What's the path leading to your downloadAction?

Answer (score -1):

In `apache2.conf` (at least that's what I tested it in):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

**Note:** This will prevent access to the files even from within HTML files. The only way they can be displayed on a page is to include them them in the HTML with [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) generated in your PHP.