# .htaccess - RewriteRule condition if url contains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess, it return 403 if user accesses image directly, but allows them to be displayed on site. I've read [(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access) in order to achieve this.

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?myapp.dev/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|JPG|jpeg|png)$ - [F]
Options -Indexes
```

What I want to do next is that if the url contains "pdf" (e.g. myapp.dev/pdf/stuff.png) I will not use or skip this code

`RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|JPG|jpeg|png)$ - [F]`

Maybe I could modify the `RewriteCond or the RewriteRule` and add a condition...

Any ideas/alternatives will be of help!

Answer (score 0):

To forbid .pdf requests , you can use :

```
RewriteRule \.pdf$ - [F,NC]
```

Edit :

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?myapp.dev/ [NC]
RewriteRule ((?!pdf).+)\.(gif|jpg|JPG|jpeg|png)$ - [F]
```

Comment: I updated my question, I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Do you mean "if the requested url is **pdf.png** or **foo.pdf**  ?

Comment: If the requested url is something like this: `myapp.dev/pdf/stuff.png`

Comment: It gave me Internal Server Error :D
I'll tweak what you gave me, I appreciate the help @starkeen.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i forgot to remove the leading backslash.

Comment: It's still forbidden :/