# prevent direct URL access to php and html pages via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I know direct URL access can be prevented via .htaccess rules but I don't know much about meta-chars or escaping.

> these are the files in my xammp/htdocs folder, accessed using
>   localhost:

```
index.php
createScheme.php
several someother.php
```

I want direct access to be enabled only for index.php and createScheme.php and all others pages should be blocked against direct access.

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by direct access?

Comment: @anubhava entering the url directly into the browser.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10236763/548225

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `.htaccess` file will only allow users to open `index.php`. Attempts to access any other files will result in a 403-error.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files "index.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

If you also want to use authentication for some of the files, you may simply add the content from your current file at the end of my example.