# How can i prevent using direct link on .mp4 file?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

So let's say we have a video in : **name.com/video/random/random.mp4**
and an html5 player in : **name.com/video/random/index.php**
How can i let the user play the .mp4 file in the player , but if he enters on **name.com/video/random/random.mp4**
 redirect him to **name.com** ?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951871/allowing-video-to-be-played-in-video-element-from-my-website-but-not-allowing?

Comment: Or what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website? Which of these have you tried to implement?

Comment: This might be some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158651/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-files-but-allow-files-in-webpages

Answer (score -4):

You should place a .htaccess file in name.com/video/random/

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - should that file contain anything? If yes, **what**?