# .htaccess deny direct access to all subdirectories and files but still allow linking from within website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a directory on our website, `./content/`, that contains a bunch of subdirectories, each of which contain their own subdirectories, etc etc.  In these subdirectories there are also a lot of .PDF docs that we need to prevent someone from being able to directly access, say by going directly to example.com/content/myfile.pdf.

We have the files referenced throughout our site and being loaded through Mozilla's PDF.js library so, obviously, we need to be able to have our PHP/HTML/JS files to be able to access them, but ONLY from within our domain.

I tried creating an .htaccess file both at our domain root and in the content folder to limit access but I'm still able to directly access them.  Here's the .htaccess contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
   RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/* [R=301,L] 

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC] 
   RewriteRule ^_content/[^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|pdf)$ - [F,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably serve it through PHP rather than using a referer check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access

Comment: I've played with a couple of the answers in the referenced post and they are not working for me.  I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by 'serve it through PHP'?

Answer (score 0):

With some modifications from the post recommended by Farkie this ended up working for me (extra HTTP_REFERER for https since we want to restrict http and https).

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(pdf)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: ....so you're saying this question already had an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10236791/8112776)?