# How to stop someone from including my images in their emails?

Tags: image, email

I just got flagged for spam because someone is hotlinking images from my website directly in their emails and sending spam with them.

I googled a lot but cant find a solution, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem depends less on the email context than on the question which http agent and/or cms you are using.

One way to go would be checking the referrer, though that might be spoofed. For the given context it should be enough though.

Wordpress has some plugins for hotlink protection, you'd have to test if they work for you. On Apache you can add referer directives to .htaccess, [this site](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/) is useful if you are new to Apache configuration.

Most other webservers like nginx or lighttpd have their own flavour of referer and location filtering. If you are on a cPanel hosting plan, cPanel as well offers some form of hotlink protection.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access) might give you more ideas how to work with referer directives.

Comment: I'm using wordpress, but they are directly copying the image links and using them in their spam emails

Answer (score 0):

you can put some kind of copyright on your images. For this you need to rewrite the HTTP protocol of the image. I think this might help, take a look at the link below: https://graphpaperpress.com/blog/protect-website-image-stealing/

Comment: I was reading more and i think you can aslo disable the rigth click on your website, look here: https://graphpaperpress.com/blog/protect-website-image-stealing/

Comment: that won't help, they are spammers, they'll still be able to get the urls to my images