# (.Htaccess) Doesn't working at all. Every time fail to prevent direct access from address bar why ?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm building a wedding photo hosting site. Where I want to Show the Images but not direct access from address by using "view source" and find direct image link. I search here a lot. I find solution.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost:81 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost:81.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Something like this :81 is my port. I've tried to test in localhost but every time its fail. Someone write there that it's may be opening from cache but I cleared cache and then try again Still same problem.
I'm using CodeIgniter/Php and I put that .htaccess file in the Image folder and once in root. What is the problem. My root folder is http://localhost:81/Project

Comment: Check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this..
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

Comment: where i need to put this .htaccess root or in image folder ?

Comment: RewriteRule ^folder/([^.]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp)$ folder/index.php?url=$1.$2 [L,QSA]

Comment: Sorry to say. Above .htaccess does not work. @masud_ma