# Embed PDF file in the html from /var/www/pdf/ directory

Tags: php, html, pdf, iframe, embed

I want to embed pdf file in my website from /var/www/pdf/ directory. I have hosted my webpage at /var/www/html/portal/index.php. I tried following ways

1) using embed

2) using iframe

```
<iframe src="../../pdf/ebook.pdf" width="900" height="750" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

3) using object

```
<object data="../../pdf/ebook.pdf#scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" width="900" height="750" type="application/pdf">
    <p>PDF cannot be displayed</p>
</object>
```

None of them working, but if I place the pdf file /var/www/html/pdf/ folder it is working fine.

For my requirement, I cannot keep the file in the web directory because public can access the PDF file directly using URL without login in to my web portal. And Also google also can index my PDF file from public search

Please help me to embed pdf

Thanks in advance

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Web Server- Apache and Server OS - CentOS 7

Comment: Does your directory `/var/www/pdf/` count with the required permissions in apache conf?

Comment: yes. I can read and write file there

Comment: Please check that apache user has the right permissions in that directory (OS level) and in its parent directory (`/var/www/`).
Double check the permission scheme in apache conf file.  What error do you see?

Comment: i re-checked . Apache user has the right permissions. I tested this in the cpanel server also. same issue when pdf directory is outside public-html directory

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `.htaccess`

**First : prevent direct access to open pdf  file**

[Refer this questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10236717/4514250)

**Second: prevent Search engine indexing**

[Refere this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/49124)

Hope it will work. I try to give this information in comment but it is not displaying properly there.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using php script

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");
@readfile('../../pdf/ebook.pdf');
```