# Can we prevent console access/download to images?

Tags: image, .htaccess, http, web-scraping

I have implemented an `htaccess` code very much like the one asked here: [(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access)

This solution works quite well to address the link OP's question, but I am looking to take it one step further.

My code currently:

- redirects direct-accessed images to a "don't do that!" page
- allows apache to serve the image (i.e. the page displays as it should)
- *allows viewing and download of the image using the developer console*

My question is: **How do we prevent that last point: the downloading of images from the developer console?** Is this possible?

I am using the Safari console, but I expect that other browsers allow similar access. The solution is surely server-side.

[image]

Please let me know if I have omitted any crucial information and I shall provide it posthaste!

Note:

In the comments below, Any Moose and I discuss watermarking the images and only releasing the non-marked images to paying subscribers. This does not prevent a malicious *subscriber* from console-scraping (let's call it) after they have paid, and then sending their downloaded images to others.

Comment: Just FYI, you'll never be able to stop screen captures...

Comment: @Any Moose That's understood by myself and the client. The site offers (very) high-res imagery as its product, however the full resolution only works when zoomed into a detail view. So screen captures are annoying, but not a huge issue. I'm checking about the php check.

Comment: @Any Moose I just tested the site "http://coloring-4kids.com" as the author answers the question you link to in your comment. They claim to use the referral system, and I still have access to the full-size image in my developer console. :-(

Comment: dang. i was hoping the php option would block it

Comment: i'll look some more

Comment: maybe just watermark view-able images and send the users to secure ftp to download real images

Comment: @Any Moose Thank you for the good ideas. The watermark may work. I was hoping to use something more elegant, for sales reasons, but if I restrict the sample images to only a few, watermarking may not even be necessary. I would still like to know if console access can be restricted though: there are a few naughty developers out there :-)

Comment: nothing i found could block access to the inspector console, lots of articles about blocking right-click save

Comment: I kinda like the watermark because it lets the content out to the world for others to see and envy over...!