Preventing the display of content directly by its link with htaccess
My content is available under certain conditions on my website page, which are as follows :
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate" disablepictureinpicture src="../videos/vid1.mp4" controls></video>
and
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|wav|mp4|webm|ogg)$ - [NC,F]
But the file is directly available through the link, and the above conditions are useless :
https://example.com/dir/videos/vid1.mp4
Is it possible to prevent content from being displayed directly by its link with .htaccess, i don't know much about the rules of the .htaccess, i truly appreciate your help.

It is not possible to reliably prevent access by means of evaluating the referrer header as you do. It is trivial to get around that "protection". Nevertheless what you implemented should work as desired. So the question is why not . Maybe that ".htaccess" file is not considered at all by your http server? How did you make sure it is? And what does your http server's access log file say what the referrer is for those requests that succeed which you would expect to get blocked?


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|wav|mp4|webm|ogg)$ - [NC,F]

But the file is directly available through the link

To block "direct" access when a user requests the URL directly (eg. types the URL into their browser) then you can just remove the first condition (RewriteCond directive) that checks for an empty Referer header. (There is no referrer when the URL is requested directly).
HOWEVER, in interests of "privacy", some users choose to suppress the Referer header in all requests (a feature in modern browsers), so you will also block these users, even though they might be requesting the resource via an embedded link on your website. There is no way around this, so generally you need to allow for an empty Referer header (as you are doing currently) and accept that resources can be requested directly.

Thank you very much for explaining the first condition (RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$) in such detail. I hope this link will also help future readers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access
